# Array type that is returned by a function in a module not defined

Tags: arrays, module, julia

I have the following module:

```
module lexer

export parseCode

function parseCode(s::String)
 lexeme::Array{UInt32, 1}
 words = Dict("dup"=>UInt32(0x40000001), "drop"=>UInt32(0x40000002),        "swap"=> UInt32(0x40000003), "+"=> UInt32(0x40000004), "-"=> UInt32(0x40000005), "x"=> UInt(0x4000000c),"/"=>UInt32(0x40000006), "%"=> UInt32(0x40000007), "if"=> UInt32(0x40000008),
  "j"=> UInt32(0x40000009), "print"=> UInt32(0x4000000a), "exit"=>UInt32(b))

  opcode = split(s)
  for w in opcode
    instruction::UInt32
    instruction = get(words,w,0)
    if instruction != 0
      push!(lexeme,instruction)
    end
  end
  push!(lexeme,UInt32(11))
  return lexeme
end
end
```

The function parseCode parses words in the string s and fetches corresponding integer values for each word and pushes them into an array lexeme.
The function then returns the array to test.jl:

```
require("stackProcessor")
require("lexer")

using stackProcessor
using lexer

#=prog=Array{UInt32,4}
prog=[3,4,0x40000001, 5, 0x40000002, 3,0x40000003, 2, 0x40000004, 0x40000000]

processor(prog)
=#
f = open("opcode.txt")
s = readall(f)
close(f)
print(s)

opcode = parseCode(s)
print(repr(opcode))
processor(opcode)
```

Opcode is the variable that should be getting a copy of the lexeme array but I get the following error:

```
oadError: UndefVarError: lexeme not defined
 in parseCode at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.2\julia\lexer.jl:11
 in include_string at loading.jl:282
 in include_string at C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\v0.4\CodeTools\src\eval.jl:32
 in anonymous at C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:84
 in withpath at C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\v0.4\Requires\src\require.jl:37
 in withpath at C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:53
 [inlined code] from C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:83
 in anonymous at task.jl:58
while loading C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.2\julia\test.jl, in expression starting on line 17
```

Funny thing is it was working fine and now it's giving me this error.
I thought in Julia, arrays are returned as a copy so I can't figure where the error is coming from.

Comment: Perhaps `lexeme` was initially left from the global environment and therefore it worked before. Either redefine it globally or the function `parseCode` needs to change.

Comment: @Dan: then do I need to pass an empty array as a function argument and then just fill the array with the new contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
lexeme::Array{UInt32, 1}
```

sounds like you were hoping to initialise a local variable ... but that isn't what that does. That's just a type assertion for an *existing* variable. I'm assuming that's line 11 that's producing the error, right?

The error is telling you that at the point were you tried to assert the type of the lexeme variable on line 11, that the particular variable hasn't yet been defined up to that point in the function.

Presumably it worked before you cleared your workspace because it was present as a global variable or something ...

If you want to initialise, do something like this instead:

```
lexeme = Array{UInt32,1}(0);
```

Comment: I overlooked the (0). I screwed up...Thanks.

Comment: An easier syntax is `UInt32[]`.